# Leaky c++ list in xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, list, memory-leaks

Some how i mananged to create a leaking list in xcode, c++.
So in my iOS project i have a list of custom objects populated like:

```
        int i=0;
        while (rawArr->isObject(i)) {
            Object::Ptr object = rawArr->getObject(i);
            SRComplexType* sr = new SRComplexType(object);
            refs.push_front(*sr);
            delete sr;
            i++;
        }
```

It seems there is something leaking here though i added a deconstructor removing all objects:

```
for(std::list<SRComplexType>::iterator list_iter = refs.begin();
    list_iter != refs.end(); list_iter++)
{
    list_iter->~SRComplexType();
}
```

}

The SRComplexType contains:

```
std::string sNo;
std::string sName;
std::string sUrl;
LocationComplexType *sLocation;
```

The sLocation (contains only two doubles and some methods) is set using:

```
this->sLocation = new LocationComplexType(locationObject);
```

The doubles in the LocationComplexType are set using:

```
    double d;
    const char * str = LatRaw.convert<string>().c_str();
    sscanf(str, "%*[^0-9]%lf",&d);
    free ((void*) str);
    this->longitude=d;
```

The instruments leak report give:

```
Leaked Object   #   Address Size    Responsible Library Responsible Frame
Malloc < varying sizes >    17  < multiple >    384 Bytes   libstdc++.6.dylib   std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&)
Malloc 32 Bytes 17  < multiple >    544 Bytes   PocoTest2   std::list<SRComplexType, std::allocator<SRComplexType> >::_M_create_node(SRComplexType const&)
Malloc 16 Bytes 1   0x72f2140   16 Bytes    PocoTest2   -[ViewController viewDidLoad]
Malloc 3.00 KB  1   0x7c6ca00   3.00 KB libstdc++.6.dylib   std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&)
Malloc < varying sizes >    17  < multiple >    560 Bytes   libstdc++.6.dylib   std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&)
Malloc 32 Bytes 17  < multiple >    544 Bytes   libstdc++.6.dylib   std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&)
```

Comment: @cli_hlt the object isn't newed in the first place, so there is no need to call `delete` or the destructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your list holds `SRComplexType` objects, so there's no need for dynamic allocation here. Just pass an `SRComplexType`:

```
refs.push_front(SRComplexType(object));
```

There is no need to delete the elements of the list either.

If `SRComplexType`'s `LocationComplexType` is dynamically allocated, you must make sure you follow the [*rule of three*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) or use a [smart pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) (`boost::scoped_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` would be good candidates).

Comment: This is correct but doesn't explain why the code above leaks. I would look to an error in `SRComplexType`.

Comment: @john I think there is not enough information to know why it leaks, but applying the fixes I suggest should fix the problem or at least narrow it down.

Comment: Thank you @juanchopanza. The leaks are now reduced to:


Malloc 32 Bytes 17 < multiple > 544 Bytes PocoTest2 StoreRefComplexType::deserialize(Poco::SharedPtr<Poco::JSON::Object, Poco::ReferenceCounter, Poco::ReleasePolicy<Poco::JSON::Object> >)